# Divide an objects css positioning on load

Tags: jquery, css, math, position, onload

I am trying to grab an objects css positioning on load of a page and then divide it by 2 on load

JS Fiddle here:

http://jsfiddle.net/27gMu/

Here is my function:

`$("#blue").delay(2000).css("top" , "/=2");`

I put the delay in just to see if it was working

Comment: Are you trying to vertically center the element?  If so, have you tried any of the pure CSS techniques for doing so?

Comment: `$("#blue").css("top", parseInt($("#blue").css("top")) / 2)`

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/27gMu/4/

```
$("#blue").delay(2000).css("top" , $("#blue").offset().top/2);
```

Comment: Ah no sorry I might have bene unclear- I'm literally just trying to move an with no relation to it's own height

Comment: So... just $("#blue").delay(2000).css("top" , 200);? Also, my example is based on offset().top, not height().

Answer (score 0):

You could do it this way: http://jsfiddle.net/27gMu/5/

```
var top = parseInt($("#blue").css("top"));
$("#blue").css("top" , top/2+"px");
```

If you want to see before and after the move...
http://jsfiddle.net/27gMu/6/

Answer (score 0):

```
var position = $("#blue").position();
$("#blue").delay(2000).css("top" , position.top / 2);
```

You can obviously do it all on one line, just thought I'd illustrate it as two separate lines for clarity.

Comment: That worked! Just waiting to for stack overflow to let me check you off